# Is it possible to run an iterative algorithm on a group in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to run an iterative algorithm on a window batch of data in Spark Structured Streaming, which corresponds to running an iterative algorithm on the groups in a RelationalGroupedDataset or KeyValueGroupedDataset.

The only options I can find (like UserDefinedAggregateFunction or mapGroupsWithState) support doing only a single pass over the data in each group. Is there any way to define a computation that does multiple passes over that group?

Algorithm 3 in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/thompson.pdf is an example of an algorithm that performs an iterative optimization on a window of data before moving to the next window.